# How do I configure my maven settings.xml in order to use the minify-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a project where the pom.xml makes use of the [minify-maven-plugin](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin). I couldn't find any documentation on how to configure the pluginRepository entry in my $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml, so I took a wild guess and added this entry:

```
<pluginRepository>
    <id>minify-maven-plugin-repo</id>
    <name>minify-maven-plugin repository</name>
    <url>https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
```

But when I run `mvn minify:minify` from my project directory I get:

```
C:\Users\J1NDH02\work\webui-war>mvn minify:minify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'minify'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from minify-maven-plugin-r
epo
[INFO] org.codehaus.mojo: checking for updates from central
[INFO] org.codehaus.mojo: checking for updates from minify-maven-plugin-repo
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin: checking for updat
es from central
[INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin: checking for updat
es from minify-maven-plugin-repo
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin' does not exist
or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 14 15:23:04 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Running `mvn -X minify:minify' generates this error message:

```
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'minify'.
[DEBUG] Loading plugin prefixes from group: org.apache.maven.plugins
[DEBUG] Loading plugin prefixes from group: org.codehaus.mojo
[DEBUG] maven-minify-plugin: using locally installed snapshot
[DEBUG] Artifact not found - using stub model: Unable to determine the latest version

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin:pom:LATEST



[DEBUG] Using defaults for missing POM org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin:pom:LATEST
[DEBUG] maven-minify-plugin: using locally installed snapshot
[DEBUG] Artifact not found - using stub model: Unable to determine the release version

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin:pom:RELEASE



[DEBUG] Using defaults for missing POM org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin:pom:RELEASE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-minify-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1851)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListByAggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

What am I getting wrong?

I'm using Maven 2.2. I added the egit plugin in case I needed it, since the minify-maven-plugin is on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upto my understanding you have to only change the pom file to include this plugin under build.

The same plugin is available in Maven central repo [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-2006536599).

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-minify</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <configuration></configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>minify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Note : I have used the version 1.7 here , you can change as per your jdk version